# pagestyle and chapterstyle design

Tags: memoir, header-footer

I am using memoir class for my thesis and I would like some help. Am fairly new to LaTeX but I am not new to programming so I can pick up easily.

I will appreciate some help in pointing me in the right direction. Here is what I want to achieve.

I am using the default memoir style, and I have created a minimal document. In my thesis, all chapters in mainmatter are publications I made to some journals. In the mainmatter then, I want to have a style as follows:

chapternamepage - blankpage - startofchapter

In chapternamepage I want to have Chapter Title as well as information about authors and citation of the publication. I have though of using epigraph for this, is this the right way ?
Secondly, for the TOC entry for each chapter, I want to have the chaptertitle as well as the citation of the publication,

I am using bibliostyle and all the citations above need to follow the same style.

Can someone help me as I start this project ?

Answer (score 3):

I would use memoir's `\chapterprecis` command instead of epigraph, since `\chapterprecis` automatically puts the text into the TOC.  And you will need a way to insert full references into the precis.  I used biblatex for that. (Theoretically bibentry/natbib should be able to do it, too but it doesn't seem to put the TOC entry part.)  The following should get you started:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=ydnt,labelyear=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{yourbibfile} % name of your bib file
\renewcommand*\precisfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\precistocfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\postchapterprecis{\end{quote}\clearpage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter title}
\chapterprecis{\fullcite{yourcitation}} % put the article cite key here
Beginning of your chapter
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding biblatex, `style=authoryear` normally is sufficient - one doesn't need to specify the `citestyle` and `bibstyle` options separately.